# What is wrong with my VBA IsNumeric function?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I cannot find what is wrong with this segment of code, every time I try to change it to something that I think will work better it shows up as an error. Many thanks in advance for your help!

This is the code, its specifically to do with the use of the isnumeric function and I am using Excel 2016 on a Mac.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet



Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set i = 1
Set n = 1

Do While ws1.Cell(i, "F") <> "End"
Num1 = ws1.Cell(i, "F")
    If IsNumeric(Num1.value) <> False And Num1 <> ""
        Set ws2.Cell(n, "B") = ws1.Cell(i, "F")
        n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: remove `.value` from `Num1` Unless you *explicitly` set Num1 to a Range object via `Dim Num1 as Range Set num1 = ws1.Cells(i,"F")`

Comment: You don't need to set variables. You don't close `do while` with `next` but with `loop`. You don't increment `i`. You don't need the `<> false`... Edit: oh the `next i` is not how you increment but `i=i+1` kind of how you did with `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you don't need VBA at all. For a non-vba solution enter this formula in Sheet2 cell B1 and drag down for as many rows as needed (in Sheet1 column F).

`=IF(AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!F1)),Sheet1!F1=""),Sheet1!F1,"")`

For a VBA solution, I cleaned up your code a bit for many syntax errors that were off. Also, heed the following:

1. Always use `Option Explicit` in your modules and declare all variable types
2. Always qualify objects with variables

(1 and 2 are *best* practices, but not required. Leaving things out can produce unexpected results).

```
Option Explicit

'... Sub Name ...
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Num1 as Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or Workbooks("myBook")
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim i as Long, n as Long
i = 1 'no need to "Set" numerical integers
n = 1

Do While ws1.Cells(i, "F") <> "End"
    Num1 = ws1.Cells(i, "F").Value2 'set this to the value2 property of the cell
    If Not IsNumeric(Num1) And Num1 <> "" 'remove .Value from variable
        ws2.Cells(n, "B").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "F").Value 'set the cells Value property equal to each ... again, Set will not work here
        n = n + 1
        i = i + 1 'need to increment i as well
    End If
Loop 'not Next I, since you are using a Do While Loop
```

Comment: If you set sheets, shouldn't you qualify the book?

Comment: @findwindow - yup, that is *really* best practice ... editing now.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped! Not enough sleep last night!